# Is final class in java same as a class with all methods declared as final and all variables declared as private

Tags: java, inheritance, final, access-modifiers

I was going through the concept of final class in java which says final class can't be inherited in java. However, if we can make all the methods of class as final and all the variables as private, won't it create the same effect as that of declaring class as final?

Take the following scenario:

Let me describe my question bit more, One of the key requirements to make class immutable is- Class should be declared as final. All variables should be final (and initialized via constructors)

Can we achieve this immutability requirement by making all methods of class as final and declaring all variables as private and final, to achieve this condition for immutability?

So, even if the class can be inherited now, we can't override the methods (as methods are final) and we can't change the variables of super class (as they are  final and also not visible - private).

Comment: No. You can declare a class with all the variables and methods as final, and that wouldn't stop you subclassing it.

Comment: that won't prevent you from creating a class inheriting from this one and adding new methods

Comment: Yes true, it won't prevent from subclassing, but can that subclass holds power to impact the super class in any way, which could not have been possible if superclass was declared final? I am talking about impact here, not whether we can or can't inherit.

Answer (score 2):

No. Making a class `final` and making its variables and methods `final` are different things.

When you make a class `final`, it can't be subclassed. That's all that `final` means for classes. A `final` class can have non-`final` variables (but its methods are implicitly `final`, yes). Example:

```
final class Foo {
    private int counter;

    public int increment() {
        return ++this.counter;
    }
}
```

When you make a  method `final`, it can't be overridden in a subclass. When you make a variable `final`, it can't be modified. Even if all of a classes variables and methods are `final`, the *class* can still be subclassed, and new methods can still be added. Example:

```
class Foo {
    public final void method1() {
        System.out.println("method1");
    }
}
class SubFoo extends Foo {
    public void method2() {
        System.out.println("method2");
    }
}
```

---

Re your fairly significant edit:

> Can we achieve this immutability requirement by making all methods of class as final and declaring all variables as private, to achieve this condition for immutability?

No, because the class can still be subclassed, and the subclass can add non-immutable features:

```
class Foo {                 // Immutable
    private final int x;

    public Foo(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public final int getX() {
        return x;
    }
}

class SubFoo extends Foo {  // NOT immutable, thanks to `y`
    private int y;

    public SubFoo(int x, int y) {
        super(x);
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return this.y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Comment: I really think nothing is wrong

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Can you answer the question now, I think you have very well explained the use of final keyword, however with the latest edit my question is more towards final & immutability of class concepts.

Comment: @aquesh - Already updated. It's best to avoid changes quite that big, though, when you can.

Comment: @aquesh - If your reference to `SubFoo` is of type `Foo`, then it's true that *through that reference* you can't change anything on it. That doesn't make the object immutable, though. It just means that the `Foo` parts of it are immutable.

Comment: This explains it well, thanks @T.J.Crowder To summarize: SubFoo is mutable  (although the super class part of it is immutable). Any object created via Foo reference, Foo obj = new Foo(10) is always immutable